# Publish Webpack Library with Multiple Entry Points

Tags: npm, webpack

I'm trying to use Webpack to publish a library that has multiple entrypoints. I have a `webpack.config.js` file like this:

```js
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    alpha: "./src/library1.js",
    beta: "./src/library2.js",
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "MyLibrary.[name].js",
    library: ["MyLibrary", "[name]"],
    libraryTarget: "umd",
    globalObject: "this",
  },
};
```

This works as advertised, and I get a dist folder with 2 files.

My question is, if I want to use this library, what do I put for the `main` property in `package.json`? My understanding is that main is a single entry point into your library, but I have 2 here (and I plan to have more).

Thanks for any help?

Answer (score 0):

You can put an index file in the `main`, something like

index.js (put in main)

====

```js
module.exports = {
  alpha: require("./dist/MyLibrary.library1.js"),
  beta: require("./dist/MyLibrary.library2.js");
}
```

module.js (put in module)

====

```js
    export alpha from "./dist/MyLibrary.library1.js";
    export beta from "./dist/MyLibrary.library2.js";
```

Answer (score 0):

I got around this using a virtual entry file in the `webpack.config.js`.

```js
const path = require("path");
const btoa = (t) => Buffer.from(t).toString('base64')

const entryText = `
  export * as alpha from './src/library1.js';
  export * as beta from './src/library2.js';
`

module.exports = {
  entry: `data:text/javascript;base64,${btoa(entryText)}`,
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "MyLibrary.js",
    library: {
      type: 'umd',
      name: ["MyLibrary"],
    }
  },
};
```

This produces a library that groups and namespaces the entries

```js
await import('https://example.com/MyLibrary.js')

console.log(MyLibrary.alpha)
console.log(MyLibrary.beta)
```